# bootstrap link in modal doesn't open new window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i create dynamically a Modal and set dynamically the href attribute of a link in the Modal. (i cant set the href when i create the modal)

If i click on the Button it doesn't open the Link of the Button

My Button shown like this in the Modal

```
<a data-temp_code="123456" class="btn btn-sm c_button js-printpdf-offer" type="button" target="_blank" href="http://someurl.com/docs/getArticle.php?code=123456"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Open Link</a>
```

Anybody know where is the problem?

I created a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rj6wc0su/3/) and there it works and i dont know why?!

Comment: Any link `<a>` with an href will open that link, *unless* there's something stopping it.  You may have some other code / event handler that returns false/preventsDefault on all links or all links in modals.  Can you step through in the browser's debugger when you click?

Comment: Please provide us with the minimal code to reproduce the error. As of now, the code does not contain the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a first look, it's something with our script, the onclick function doesn't append your href to the `<a>`'s href.
Try to follow these to debug your code:

1- `$(document).ready(function(){.....});`

2- Try to console.log the href after you append it: `$('.js-new-link').attr()`

3- Make sure there is no other function that overrides the event by returning false or preventDefault

4- Place your script at the end of the `<body>` tag

Answer (score 0):

i have a "click" - event on the link too... i comment it out and after that it works... but i don't know why?!
this is the code of the click event?

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.js-printpdf-offer', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if($('#onlyInternModal.in').length > 0) {
        $('#onlyInternModal.in').modal("hide");
    }

    var temp_code = $(this).data("temp_code");
    var make = $('.js-hersteller').val();
    var model = $('.js-typ').val();
    var model_id = $('.js-model-id').val();
    var caption = '';

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/saveAction.php",
            data: {
                temp_code:temp_code,
                make:make,
                model:model,
                model_id:model_id,
                caption:caption,
            },
            success: function(data) {

            }
    });
});
```

Comment: ah f**** i delete the preventDefault and it works... sometimes i not to see the wood for the trees ;-)
thx for the quick help to everybody...